# Try to do a multiple field search using firestore

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am trying to find a way to do multiple field searches that pull all the objects that I am looking for, for example, if I want to find all the programming job in my specialty in a specific zip code so and I have three objects that have those two components that match in a sense.

Code JS

```
var jobRef = dataFirebase
                .collection("Jobs")
                .where("Specialty" , "==" , "Programming")
                .where("ZipCode" , "==" , "12345");
```

should in a sense pull ALL the objects that I am looking for but when I try to run the code it returns just one of them only. Also, I used an inequality but you cannot use an inequality in two different fields that is the error I keep on receiving.

Comment: Please also show the code that retrieves the results for this query. In addition, add a screenshot of the one document that shows up, and a document that doesn't show up (but that you think should show up).

Comment: Hello, I found the issue I had in terms of the inequality, I will be deleting the question. It was my cap sensitive and misspelling in the specific data information I am looking for.

Comment: Good to hear Jaffer. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help catch the problem next time.